# Tomcat and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: java, ios, tomcat

We have a server running tomcat and clients using iphones. On the iphone the application uses ASIHTTPRequest in a pooled setup (I dont have the details about this part). Quite often the server will stop responding and when checking netstat we find that there are hundreds of connections in CLOSE_WAIT. Now what I can determine is that the server is waiting to send its final ACK to the phone but the phone is no longer there or not responding so the connections continue to hang until tomcat is restarted.

I determined this by noticing 1 byte left in the Recv-Q on the server to each and every one of these connections and also by this from msdn: "On the side that closed the connection you will have FIN_WAIT_2, on the side that is to send the final FIN_ACK and ACK you will have CLOSE_WAIT."

Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/10/09/tcp-connections-hanging-in-the-close-wait-and-fin-wait-2-state.aspx

So my question is there a bug in ASIHTTPRequest wherein it closes the connection before it receives the ACK? Or is there way to configure Ubuntu to kill these connections after X time?

**Additional Info**

Tomcat connector configuration:
`<Connector port="8080" 
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
  connectionTimeout="3000" 
  connectionLinger="-1"
  tcpNoDelay="true"
  acceptCount="300"
  maxThreads="400"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="100"
  redirectPort="8443" 
/>`

sysctl opts:

```
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
fs.file-max = 13337
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 6
```

netstat of an offending connection:

```
root@example.com:~# netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN
tcp        1      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:8080       xx.xx.xx.xx:49864     CLOSE_WAIT
```

*IP's removed to protect the innocent*

**Update**

It's a bit odd but I think I should add that this seems only to occur when our code is running on slicehost. Running the same "everything" on an Amazon EC2 instance does not exhibit the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the hosting provider and not a problem in the server or library.

Comment: do you know what exactly the issue was? im facing the same issue. :(

Comment: We used SliceHost / Rackspace and our account had "shared" bandwidth; as far as we can tell it had something to do with the way they shared / enforced the bandwidth. When we switched to Amazon, the issue went away completely.